# How to create a pop-up (ease-in) fixed header

Tags: javascript, jquery, interaction

I am talking about the fixed header you get in your facebook profile page. Once you scroll to the end of the cover picture, you get a secondary header bar which then becomes fixed till you scroll above the cover image.

Is there any name for this? Also, how do I go about creating a prototype for this interaction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are called Sticky Headers and Sticky Footers

Look at the following links

- [link 1](http://www.jay-han.com/2011/11/10/simple-smart-sticky-navigation-bar-with-jquery/)
- [link 2](https://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/sticky-header-and-footer-using-css/)
- [link 3](http://www.sutanaryan.com/jquery/how-to-create-fixed-menu-when-scrolling-page-with-css-and-jquery/)

Answer (score -1):

You can add popup and/or sticky bar both on any website such as wordpress, blogger, any framework website or html website using WEBSOLINK widget. Check this instruction here: https://blog.websolink.com/add-popup-and-sticky-bar/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).